# How can I use react-native-fbsdk with build platform?

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, carthage, react-native-fbsdk

I am using buddybuild to build our app & I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the `react-native-fbsdk`? The docs tell us to put the Library in `~/Documents/FacebookSDK`. But for build tools such as Buddybuild (travis, circle, etc...), I'm not sure what we're supposed todo here?

Our app does not use cocoapods, it uses carthage.

Any ideas?

So far the only option would be to install cocoapods & install the dependency from there?

Update:

I found that Carthage supports the swift SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

However I don't think the react-native-fbsdk package works with the swift implementation

Related:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/110631459337469/
- https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1183

Answer (score 2):

For those who are not using CocoaPods for any reason, here´s how replicate  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642866/165622 main idea into AppCenter:

First of all, you need to copy the Facebook Sdk files somewhere into your project. In my case I´d put them at {PROJECT}/ios/Facebook

Then you need to create a `appcenter-post-clone.sh` file at the root of your react-native project (as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/) making sure to add:

`ln -s $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/ios/Facebook $HOME/Documents/FacebookSDK`

Note that the `Documents` folder already exists there, so need to create it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an issue which is currently waiting for the patch here [bug report](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/341), meanwhile, a solution for buddybuild could by creating a symbolic link for the hard-coded path.

For more information regarding post-clone see [postclone docs](https://docs.buddybuild.com/builds/custom_build_steps.html)

```
# File: buddybuild_postclone.sh

# Creating virtual symbolic link for FB SDK for buddybuild
mkdir ~/Documents  
ln -s $BUDDYBUILD_WORKSPACE/ios/libs/FacebookSDK ~/Documents/FacebookSDK
```

Comment: @YaronLevi check my answer